# Trying to access Request attributes from a post rquest to log in database PHP Slim 3

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

Trying to access protected property Slim\Http\Request::$attributes but I am getting an error saying

```
Cannot access protected property Slim\Http\Request::$attributes
```

How can I access these from a post request.  Here is my post

```
$this->post('/error/log', function ($request, $response, $arg){
    $parsedBody = (object)$request->getParsedBody();
    $this->logger->info("Slim-Skeleton '/api/v1/error/log' route");
    if ( $this->has('ErrorLogService') ) {
        $requestObj = new \stdClass();
        $requestObj->data = new \stdClass();
        $requestObj->request = $request;
        $requestObj->data = $parsedBody;
        $resultData = $this->ErrorLogService->saveErrors($requestObj);
    }
    $http_header = array_key_exists('validation_errors', $resultData ) ? 400 : 200;
    $http_header = array_key_exists('error', $resultData ) ? 200 : $http_header;
    //var_dump($http_header);die();
    $json = unserialize(str_replace(array('NAN;','INF;'),'0;',serialize($resultData)));
    return $response->withJson($json, $http_header, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

})->add(new Authentication())->setName('error-log');
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the error message that you've posted is not complete, I'd guess that the problem occurrs when you attempt to log error:

```
$requestObj->request = $request;
...
$resultData = $this->ErrorLogService->saveErrors($requestObj);
```

The `$request` variable here represents HTTP request and is instance of `Slim\Http\Request`. Being property of the `$requestObj`, it is passed to the log service.

Could it be that the `ErrorLogService` is attempting to access the protected properties? It's likely that there's some "magic" in it that tries to persist the whole object and every property of it.

If that is the case you can solve the problem by:

- reconsidering what information about the HTTP request should really be logged.
- changing the code that attempts to access non-public properties.

I advise to go for the first option, because I know that Slim request objects contain excessive information, way more than you want to log. Check that yourself with `var_dump($request)`.